# Странный ответ от --JupyterWebsocketPersonality.list_kernels=True

Tags: python, anaconda

Здравствуйте!

По совету https://github.com/jupyter/kernel_gateway/issues/203 выполнил команду

> --JupyterWebsocketPersonality.list_kernels=True

в Anaconda Prompt и получил:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это?